# Ubuntu clock is slow, no Internet. How do I prohibit writing to CMOS clock?

Tags: 12.04, time, clock

Almost each time after I close the laptop lid, the system clock gets slow:

[image: local time vs timeanddate.com]

I am not the first one facing this problem, and there are a lot of recipes like
"make your clock synchronized", but: ***Internet connection is not available when the computer awakes.*** Some people mention that the CMOS clock is not really accurate -- I can live with that.

I want my computer clock to be, well, a clock, not an ntp client.

So:

***How do I tell the system to use the CMOS time and never write to the CMOS clock?***

Ubuntu 12.04 Precise LTS.

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** the RTC *is* not the problem? (Maybe it's slowing down because the battery providing back-up power to the RTC is reaching its end-of-life?) Have you checked your RTC? (Because if the RTC *is the problem*, the better solution would be to reset the clock using ntp when coming back from sleep *after the network has come up*...

Comment: @Fabby the network _will not come up_. (Plugging in the modem (~2-3 minutes) to set the clock is not considered seriously.) And yes, it is not the battery because the computer is not unplugged.